# Argument of \NROrg@ifthenelse has an extra }

Tags: errors, compiling, moderncv

I presume the problem I have been encountering is quite trivial. But I could not find any help via Google, so I am asking the experts. The problem is the following:
I want to create a Cirriculum using moderncv. But when I run TeXworks
(I'm using Windows 7), it returns me an error saying:

```
    Argument of \NROrg@ifthenelse has an extra }.
    <inserted text> 
    \par 
    l.30 \cventry{2008-2011}{Oberstufenschule Zulg}
    {{Steffisburg}}
```

Since the error is referring to my apparently badly written code, I shall put it here:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

    \moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
    \recomputelengths
    \fancyfoot{}

    \firstname {Mario}
    \lastname {Andricic}
    \title {Curriculum Vitae}
    \address{Neumattstrasse 21}{3600 Thun}
    \mobile {+41 79 550 58 84} 
    \phone {+41 33 437 37 17}
    \email {rio.andricic@bluewin.ch}
    \nopagenumbers{}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \section{Info}


    \cvline{Geburtsdatum}{\small 16.06.1995 Thun\normalsize}
    \cvcomputer{Nationalität}{\small Schweiz\normalsize}{Führerausweis}
    {\small vorhanden\normalsize}}

    \section{Bildung}
    \cventry{2006-2008}{Mittelstufenschule Schönau}{Steffisburg}
    \cventry{2008-2011}{Oberstufenschule Zulg}Steffisburg}
    \cventry{2011-2014}{Gymnasium und Wirtschaftsmittelschule Thun-Schadau}{Thun}

    \end{document}
```

As I have already said, I was looking for the answer on Google but either I could not find it or I do not have the knowledge to learn from similar errors.
Please help me!

Greetings :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The lines `\cvcomputer{Nationalität}{\small Schweiz\normalsize}{Führerausweis}{\small vorhanden\normalsize}}` and `\cventry{2008-2011}{Oberstufenschule Zulg}Steffisburg}` look suspicious to me, the former seems to have an excess `}` (after `\normalsize}`) while the latter seems to lack a `{` (before `Steffisburg`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `moderncv.cls` (2013/04/29 v1.5.1) I found the following line:

```
% usage: \cventry[spacing]{years}{degree/job title}{institution/employer}localization}{optionnal: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description}
```

That are one optional and *six* mandatory arguments. But you have only given three arguments to `\cventry`, thus the first `\cventry` is stealing from the following code to get its arguments:

```
\cventry{2006-2008}{Mittelstufenschule Schönau}{Steffisburg}{\cventry}{2008-2011}{Oberstufenschule Zulg}
```

The `\cventry` in the forth mandatory argument causes the trouble.

Answer (score 5):

This is the right code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths
\fancyfoot{}

\firstname {Mario}
\lastname {Andricic}
\title {Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Neumattstrasse 21}{3600 Thun}
\mobile {+41 79 550 58 84}
\phone {+41 33 437 37 17}
\email {rio.andricic@bluewin.ch}
\nopagenumbers{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Info}


\cvline{Geburtsdatum}{\small 16.06.1995 Thun\normalsize}
\cvcomputer{Nationalität}{\small Schweiz\normalsize}{Führerausweis}
{\small vorhanden\normalsize}

\section{Bildung}
\cventry{2006-2008}{Mittelstufenschule Schönau}{Steffisburg}{}{}{}
\cventry{2008-2011}{Oberstufenschule Zulg}{Steffisburg}{}{}{}
\cventry{2011-2014}{Gymnasium und Wirtschaftsmittelschule Thun-Schadau}{Thun}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

First of all, `\cventry` has 6 arguments. You can leave empty the last 4.

Moreover, the line

```
{\small vorhanden\normalsize}}
```

had an extra `}` and the line

```
\cventry{2008-2011}{Oberstufenschule Zulg}Steffisburg}
```

missed a `{`.

Comment: You have answered my question in a satisfying way. Thank you!